# Map on HList in method with Poly1 based on type parameter of class

Tags: scala, functional-programming, hlist, shapeless, type-level-computation

I have class, parameterized with `HList` and some other type. How can I use `map` on `HList` in one of its methods?

Compilation of this code throws `java.lang.AssertionError`:

```
class Test[L <: HList, P](l: L, p: P) {
  type Cont[T] = (P, T)
  object generator extends (Id ~> Cont) {
    def apply[T](t: T) = p -> t
  }
  def test(implicit m: Mapper[generator.type, L]) = {
    l map generator
  }
}

new Test(1 :: HNil, 'a).test // java.lang.AssertionError
```

My goal is this kind of result:

```
type Cont[T] = (Symbol, T)
val p = 'a
object generator extends (Id ~> Cont) {
  def apply[T](t: T) = p -> t
}

scala> (1 :: 'b' :: HNil) map generator
res0: shapeless.::[(Symbol, Int),shapeless.::[(Symbol, Char),shapeless.HNil]] = ('a,1) :: ('a,b) :: HNil
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in the Scala compiler (both 2.9.2 and 2.10.0-RC1).

As a workaround, if you split the creation of the instance of `Test` and the invocation of the `test` method across two expression then it works as expected,

```
scala> val t = new Test(1 :: HNil, 'a)
t: Test[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil],Symbol] = Test@4b153b34

scala> t.test
res0: shapeless.::[(Symbol, Int),shapeless.HNil] = ('a,1) :: HNil
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately workaround is useless since `Test` should be `implicit class`.

Comment: Understood. It might be possible to restructure the code in a way which avoids the scalac bug and gets you the form that you're looking for. Head over to the shapeless mailing list and take it from there.